# Send a SOAPMessage with SAAJ to a servlet on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, saaj

I have a web application running on Tomcat 6 and a Java-programmed client application.
The client send SOAPMessage to a Proxy servlet that validate the message and forwards it to the right web service.
I use SAAJ to send SOAPMessage on client:

```
    SOAPMessage soap = soapFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPBody body = soap.getSOAPBody();
    body.addDocument( document );

    SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection = soapFactory.createConnection();

    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(soap, PROXY_URL);
```

That work fine, but I need that Proxy servlet implements sessions using cookie (JSESSION).

How can I retrive that cookie from the *response*? Do you know if exists a better way to do it?

Comment: First, SOAP web services depending on session states are not a good idea; technical interfaces **should** (not shall) be stateless.

I do not understand your question. Is your problem a) to implement the proxy servlet or b) to retrieve the cookie set in Proxy servlet from `SOAPMessage`?

Comment: Proxy manages client sessions and interacts with two WS in stateless mode. Clients can send message only to Proxy, Proxy is not a WS, is a Servlet.

Comment: My problem is to retrive the cookie set in proxy servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mattevigo: I believe you are mixing two things.
SOAP is a application level protocol which in your case using HTTP transport protocol. You have choices of opening a HTTPConnection and do lower level work and can use HTTP cookie for session management OR you can open SOAPConnection to work with directly SOAP message at higher level.I believe SAAJ api as such does not let you work on HTTP data directly. What you can do is open HTTP connection for communication and use SAAJ API to parse incoming XML and fetch data.